# How to enable WebGL support in Delphi 10.1 webbrowser component?

Tags: delphi, webgl, delphi-10.1-berlin, twebbrowser

We need to play a 3D viewer in our delphi 10.1 application. For this we are using Delphi `TWebBrowser` component to emulate browser. But `TWebBrowser` in Delphi does not support WebGL. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You should be clear whether you're using VCL or FMX, because the `TWebBrowser` is *entirely* different for each.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `TWebBrowser` component which encapsulates Internet Explorer, you could use [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) (`CEF`).
But then you have to ship your app with additional DLLs, just to keep that in mind.

See [here](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3) vor V3 or [here](https://www.briskbard.com/index.php?lang=en&pageid=cef) for V4.

Comment: That is, if OP is using VCL, which was not specified.

Comment: CEF4Delphi has VCL and FMX components to embed a Chromium browser with WebGL but only in Windows. thedh should clarify if his/her application runs on Windows or some other platform.